# Creating new objects in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've been creating some code in JNI and most of it is working fine but I haven't been able to create an instance of a Java object from C++ as my Java IDE gives me the following error:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000070e1e0d2, pid=10100, tid=0x0000000000000d90
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   V  [jvm.dll+0x15e0d2]
>
> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>   C:\Users\Alienware\Documents\Netbeans Projects\NativeTest\hs_err_pid10100.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

The Java object I'm trying to create is:

```
public class ConstructorObject {    
    public ConstructorObject() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and the native class is:

```
public class NativeNewObject
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeLibrary");
    }

    private native void callConstructorObject0();

    public void callConstrtuctorObject() {
        callConstructorObject0();
    }
}
```

The C++ code is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_main_NativeNewObject_callConstructorObject0(JNIEnv *e, jobject obj) {
    jclass c = e->FindClass("ConstructorObject");
    jmethodID mid = e->GetMethodID(c, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject newObj = e->NewObject(c, mid);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered adding any error checking to your code?

Comment: To determine which line is failing? I did that, I just deleted here as I thought it would be taking up space. The line that is failing is the GetMethodID line. The code runs to there and crashes with that message.

Comment: It transpires that the line which is really failing is the `FindClass()` call, which is returning a zero. *Proper* error-checking would have detected that.

Answer (score 4):

Was your class lookup successful?  Did you see that the value of `c` contained something other than NULL?

Comment: No, the problem is on the GetMethodID line.

Comment: @Ghost If `c` contains null, then the problem would be reported when you use `c`, not when you set `c` to a valid value of `null` because you couldn't find the class in the lookup.   Did you actually verify the contents of variable `c`, or are you just going by line number of the crash?  If `c` has a non-zero integer value, odds are it is a good value.

Comment: My god I can't believe I made that mistake again. The problem was I didn't take into account the layout of the package structure. It was "main/ConstructorObject" not "ConstructorObject" otherwise the reference was null. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, I had a problem on the line of constructor fetching, I had something like this:

```
jmethodID mid = e->GetMethodID(c, "<init>", "()V");
```

I changed it for

```
jmethodID mid = e->GetMethodID(c, "<init>", "void(V)");
```